# WPF application database support

Tags: c#, wpf, database, .net-4.5, visual-studio-2013

I started a project a year ago, as of yet, it's unfinished. I'm picking it back up with VS2013 and the front end part of it will be a .NET 4.5 WPF application (used to be a WinForms application)

The database support was SQL Compact 4.0 I believe (.SDF file). I'm using Entity Framework as well.

At this point, are there better options ? I want something that does not require a server, pretty much as I was using SQL Compact 4.0.

Thanks.

EDIT: Turns out I'll use LocalDB provided with the VS2013 installation. :)